# Why are my ul and ol lists not displaying properly in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, list

Something seems to be breaking the display of lists (`ul` and `ol`) in IE7. They work fine in IE8, FF, Safari etc but not IE7 and IE6.

I just want them to be displayed normally: `ul` lists should show bullet points and `ol` lists should show numbers.

I've narrowed it down to the first 1000 lines of code in `styles_layout.css`... ;)

Actually, I believe it has something to do with the following styles:

```
* { margin: 0; } 

html, body { height: 100%; } 

.wrapper 
{ 
  min-height: 100%; 
  height: auto !important; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto -39px; 
}
```

Have a look here: http://www.olvarwood.com.au/olvarwoodonline/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=2, login as a `guest`

Comment: hmm  narrowed it down to:

* {
 margin: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -39px;
}

Comment: Maybe the negative left margin is cutting the list markers off.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in a web page I've been designing. Somehow the bullets disappear with a negative margin for the div containing the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself through trial and error:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This stops Ol's and Ul's from displaying properly in IE7 and IE6. I have no idea why...

Comment: That's a bad reset. Try Eric Meyer's reset. Much nicer :)

Comment: Understatement: that's a *horrible* reset. The * selector should be sued with extreme prejudice: it can have very negative effects on CSS performance (the cascades are ridiculous) and there are very few elements where you actually want to globally affect a style, as you've discovered - lists want margins.

Answer (score 10):

IE7 and below style ul elements like this:

```
ul {
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

Good browsers style ul elements like this:

```
ul {
  padding-left: 40px
}
```

It's better explained by Eric Meyer here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Consistent_List_Indentation
and the section "Finding Consistency" will tell you what you do.

Comment: Eric's article definitely helped me. Great link. It makes perfect sense after that. I just set margin:0 to all OLs and then set the padding-let to 40px and now its cross browser consistent in IE7 and all the other ones. Nice.!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the ul/li elements have inherited the zero-margin property.

Answer (score 0):

I won't even pretend to be an expert on css, I get my butt kicked by it all the time, but I just happened to run into this, although my situation was a bit different.

I ended up having to specify a class tied to ul and set the list-type.

```
.classname ul { list-style disc inside }
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, Yes I had tried something similar but it made no difference. Thanks anyway though